# What does "go it on your own" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

**Context**: I am reading [*Success*](http://www.success.com/mobilenodeview/23790) magazine and the topic is "*Take three steps to open yourself to learning.*"

I am trying to figure out what "You can go it on your own mean," in this paragraph.

> Because you're human, this process [learning new things] will be
>   uncomfortable, and this discomfort is called growth. **You can go it on
>   your own**, but it's easier with help from a friend, a parent, a
>   mentor... a coach, whether formal or not.

I did a Google search on idioms for "go in" but there was none available.

Comment: "you can do it on your own" - by yourself. alone.

Comment: I searched for this and the almost overwhelmingly more common phrase is **go it on your own**. Can you please provide a source?

Comment: The source says *go **it***, which is what you write first; but in your title, your quotation, and your search you used *go **in***. I have corrected these to *it*, except the search term.

Comment: Sorry about the first edit, I just assumed the text was correct and edited the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### My incorrect answer was

"Go in" means "enter", "on your own" means "by yourself".

> You can enter [the process] by yourself, but...

---

#### Apparently I was answering a question that wasn't asked.  My bad!

The idiom "***go it alone***" (see [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+it+alone) for example) means "*undertake without assistance*".  I suppose the author rephrased it a bit to be "go it *on your own*", yet intended that phrase to mean "**go it alone**".

Comment: in the OP's context, I'd prefer using the word "undertake".

Comment: Yes, that too.  "I go in for swimming" - "I participate in the sport of swimming", but "for" seems amiss.

Comment: The correct quotation is *go **it***, which OP wrote originally in one place but miswrote as *go **in*** in three others.

Comment: Please see my other comment.

Comment: @victor _go it_ is an idiom, so _go it on your own_ is not a typo.

Comment: It is?  OK, I answered a wrong question then.

Comment: @jimsug.  Could you post a link to some place explaining that idiom, please?

Comment: @vic a quick search reveals a large number of definitions - you may need to `ctrl+f` to find the phrase, but here's a few different sources: [go it alone](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/alone) [go it alone](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-it-alone#go-it-alone_1) [go it alone](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=go) [go it alone](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/go-it-alone_2)

Comment: Thanks.  The first one is the definition of "alone".  The second is a circular definition.  Searching for "go it alone" (in quotes) finds it, however.  I can't delete an accepted answer, will edit.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, it will mean, to "self-learn", that is, to learn on one's own. And the paragraph does make it clear that self learning can be difficult perhaps hence it is recommended to take the support of a friend/coach/mentor.